# Repeated measures ANOVA with unbalanced data

Tags: anova, spss, repeated-measures

I am a master's student, and I need your help. I did experiment on one group of rats, the group was tested during 8 days, this is the first stage. The same group was also tested again but this time the test phase was 7 days. I tried to do my analysis using ANOVA repeated measures but I had a problem with the days. I want to know the difference in the 2 tests but the days are not the same number. I don't know how to handle it. If there is any way to do the analysis using repeated measures ANOVA.

I tried to use repeated measures ANOVA within subjects effect. My first factor will be `test` with 2 levels (test 1 & 2), second factor is `day` with the level of? Here is the problem! If I write 8 there will be extra day in test 2 and the analysis can't run!